# question about from fastai.vision import *

Tags: python

I have successfully installed the `fastai` library，there is no problem when I try `import fastai`.
But when I try `from fastai.vision import *`, it gets an error:

```
 ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
```

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Translate this error message to english, please

Comment: According to Google translate, this means "Module not found".